# Constructing an object with variable amounts of data tacked on

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm working on a message-passing runtime system that has existing message allocation code that looks like this when a messages contain variable-length data:

```
struct MsgBase {
  void* operator new(size_t obj_size, int arr1_size, int arr2_size);
};
struct Msg : MsgBase {
  double *arr1;
  double *arr2;
};
struct MsgBase {
  void* operator new(size_t obj_size, int arr1_size, int arr2_size) {
    size_t offsets[2];
    offsets[0] = obj_size;
    offsets[1] = obj_size + sizeof(double)*arr1_size;
    Msg *m = (Msg *)malloc(offsets[1] + sizeof(double)*arr2_size);
    m->arr1 = (char*)m + sizeof(double)*arr1_size;
    m->arr1 = (char*)m->arr1 + sizeof(double)*arr2_size;
    return m;
  }
};
```

For hardware-interface reasons, the message has to be allocated as one big buffer, and copying into such a buffer after the fact would kill performance<sup>1</sup>.

And (*lots of*) client code that does

```
Msg *msg = new (12, 17) Msg;
msg->arr1[6] = 543.43;
```

The problem we've just encountered is that g++ 4.4 (unlike earlier versions) is zeroing out `sizeof(Msg)` bytes starting at `msg` before the pointer is returned to us, so those offset pointers into the buffer are not preserved. Thus, the second line of code results in a segfault.

The zeroing doesn't happen if we declare a constructor `Msg::Msg()`, but my intuition is that the compiler would be within its rights to zero out the allocation before calling the constructor anyway.

- So, is my intuition correct, that code like this has no real assurance of working, even if we explicitly declare the constructor?
- Assuming that the code above won't continue to work, do I have any hope to preserve the client interface? How would the replacement for this look?

---

Notes: the `MsgBase` class and attendant `operator new()` are generated from a client-provided interface definition that says something like

```
message Msg {
  double arr1[];
  double arr2[];
};
```

While the client code is responsible for defining `Msg` itself and ensuring that it inherits from `MsgBase`. So, we can change anything about `MsgBase`, but pretty much nothing about `Msg` without forcing that on existing application code.

1. Don't tell me to go profile that. We've benchmarked this heavily (we run on several of the top 10 from the [top500](http://top500.org)), and are trying to be zero-copy wherever we can. We currently make no copies here, and regressions would suck.

Comment: As a point of interest, the 'lifetime dead store elimination' optimization added in GCC 6 made this issue even worse. We now have to compile with `-fno-lifetime-dse` to disable that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that anything written into the memory by `operator new` is not guaranteed to be preserved.  So no, you can't retain the current broken call syntax.

Use a factory function and the library-provided placement new.  Something like this:

```
struct Msg
{
  double* const arr1;
  double* const arr2;
private:
  Msg(double* p1, double* p2) : arr1(p1), arr2(p2) {}
  Msg(const Msg&); // deleted copy-constructor
  // having const members prevents assignment operator from being implicitly generated
public:
  static Msg* Create( size_t arr1_len, size_t arr2_len )
  {
      void* raw = ::operator new(sizeof (Msg) + (1 + arr1_len + arr2_len) * sizeof (double));
      // note ugly math to properly align double, assumes sizeof (double) is a power of 2
      // consider using alignof (double) instead of sizeof (double) if your compiler supports it
      double* p = reinterpret_cast<double*>((reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(raw) + sizeof (Msg) + sizeof (double)) & ~(sizeof (double) - 1));
      return new (raw) Msg(p, p + arr1_len);
  }
};
```

NOTE: You could possibly retain the current syntax by using thread-local variables and a constructor... basically your custom `operator new` would put either the pointers or the sizes into the TLS, then the constructor would read the TLS and set the pointers appropriately.  I think I would pass the sizes, since the compiler might be asking `operator new` for a little extra memory and stuffing debugging information in front of the actual object.

Comment: I like how you're thinking on the TLS bits. That's the kind of outside-the-box idea I was hoping for.

Comment: @Novelocrat: Is a hint in the right direction enough, or do you need code?  In `g++`, the `__thread` keyword is used to make variables thread-local, that makes sure that simultaneous calls on different threads to this placement new - constructor team don't overwrite each others data.

Comment: The hint's enough; I just wasn't sure if I was going to get any other answers. Unless something gets stuck in the application code's message constructors, there's still a chance of failure even with TLS. If I'm going to make intensive changes, I'll probably go with something (e.g. a proper factory method) that simply doesn't have this sort of fragility at all.